# Initialize the List of Record Syntax Data Type

Tags: haskell

I can initialize the list of Int such beautiful way:

```
[2, 4 .. 20]
```

And I am just wondering if there is any to initialize the list of my datatype in such manner.  Something like this, but using more haskell way:

```
data SieveElement = SieveElement { index :: Int,
                                   flag ::  Bool 
                                   } deriving (Show)

prepareSieve start end step
             | start > end = []
             | otherwise = [SieveElement start True] ++ (prepareSieve (start + step) end step)

let s = prepareSieve 2 20 2
```

Comment: Use `SieveElement start True : prepareSieve (start + step) end step` to insert item as the head.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using list comprehensions:

```
[SieveElement i True | i <- [2, 4 .. 20]]
```

Answer (score 3):

While [Sjoerd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703195/initialize-the-list-of-record-syntax-data-type/7703259#7703259) is the right way to go for your code, I felt it was worth pointing out that the nice list range syntax is available for more than just `Int`s.  Any data type which is an instance of [`Enum`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#t:Enum) can be used in lists in the same way:

- `[a..]`    is translated as `enumFrom a`,
- `[a,b..]`  is translated as `enumFromThen a b`,
- `[a..c]`   is translated as `enumFromTo a c`, and
- `[a,b..c]` is translated as `enumFromThenTo a b c`.

This doesn't really work for your example, though, since I don't know that there's a good way to declare such an instance for your type.  For instance, it seems that you want `succ (SieveElement i f) = SieveElement (succ i) f`—ignoring the flag—but then it's not clear how you implement `toEnum :: Int -> a` and `fromEnum :: a -> Int` in such a way that you can construct all of the `SieveElements`, with both `True` and `False` flags.

---

**Edit:** As newacct pointed out in the comments, there's no need for `toEnum` to cover the entire range: consider `Float` and `Double`, for which `toEnum` produces only whole numbers.  As another example, `fromEnum (pi :: Double) == (3 :: Int)`.  So you could define an instance of `Enum`.  However, doing this naïvely won't work:

```
data SieveElement = SieveElement { index :: Int
                                 , flag  :: Bool }
                  deriving (Show)

-- Warning: broken!
instance Enum SieveElement where
  succ (SieveElement i f) = SieveElement (succ i) f
  pred (SieveElement i f) = SieveElement (pred i) f
  toEnum i = SieveElement i False -- or True
  fromEnum (SieveElement i _) = i
```

This has some bad behavior with the `enumFrom*` family of methods:

```
*Main> [SieveElement 2 True .. SieveElement 3 True]
[SieveElement {index = 2, flag = False},SieveElement {index = 3, flag = False}]
```

Unfortunately, since [the default `enumFrom*` implementations](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/GHC-Enum.html#Enum) are in terms of `fromEnum`/`toEnum`, you'll lose your flag.  You could reimplement these, of course, but I'm not sure what semantics you would want for something like `[SieveElement 2 True, SieveElement 4 False .. SieveElement 10 True]`.  In general, these are some more, better, reasons why I think [Sjoerd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703195/initialize-the-list-of-record-syntax-data-type/7703259#7703259) is absolutely the right way to go.

Comment: who says it must "construct all of the SieveElements, with both True and False flags"?

Comment: @newacct: Fair enough, I suppose—I just sort of assumed that, since every instance I can think of (basically the default ones and other numbers) supports that behavior, and there are no instances defined for types like `(,)` or `Complex a` where you could implement sensible enumeration behavior but `fromInt`/`toInt` would be slightly tricky.

Comment: for Float and Double, toEnum can only generate whole numbers

Comment: @newacct: Well, I'm just not on top of my game at all.  Thanks.

Comment: @newacct: I incorporated your observation into my answer, and in doing so found another reason why I think `Enum` is a bad fit for `SieveElement`.  Thanks again for catching that error on my part, and I hope I didn't introduce another one.